# rebuilding a java application

Tags: disassembly, java, byte-code

I wish to rebuild MotiveWave, a charting tool, from its jars. This application has a feature (probably in one of the class files but I don't know which) that i want to build upon. I mean I want to inherit that class and use it in another custom class. The jars are without the source code. I have tried jd to view the source of jars and was able to view some of the code. What I want is to build and run it in debug and then access that specific feature using the UI to see which code gets triggered.
Is this possible/ Can anybody point me to the right direction as I am totally lost right now.

Comment: Have you tried adding it to your classpath and calling the methods you're trying to use?